# Printing a certain string in assembly

Tags: assembly

I have this assembly code:

```
push dword ' You'
push dword 'Hey'
push esp
call printf
```

It prints only 'Hey'.
How can I fix it to print 'Hey You'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add a space after the word Hey like so 'Hey '.

Why? because 'Hey' is a dword, thats 4 bytes: `'H' 'e' 'y' 0` (null), `printf` prints until the first null, therefore you get only 'Hey '.
But 'Hey ' is `'H' 'e' 'y' ' '`, and the first null will now be after 'You'.